# Is the centralizer $C(a)$ of an element $a \in G$ a normal subgroup of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've tried showing that $gC(a)g^{-1} \subseteq C(a),\,\forall g \in G$ by showing that the element $ gxg^{-1}, x \in C(a)$ also comutes with $a$, but I wasn't able to. Is $C(a)$ normal? Is there a condition to the choice of $a$ that I'm not aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed another part of the question. The general fact is that $gC(a)g^{-1}=C(gag^{-1})$ (it is easy to check). So the simplest condition
which implies that $C(a)$ is normal is the condition that
the cyclic subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ is normal. That is not an "if and only if" condition.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

$C(a)$ is very rarely normal. For example, in $S_3$, $C((1,2))=
\langle(1,2)\rangle$ in fact malnormal.